# Dropdown menu isn't overlapping parent div (bootstrap2)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a select dropdown that once opened becomes 'hidden' from view within its parent container - the dropdown is generated via the ddSlick.js library (to create dropdown with images).

```
<div class="span6 column2">
   <div class="form-section">
        <div id="iconSelector"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

With the ddSlick.js it generates the following - I want to have this content in dd-container overlapping the parent div. Any ideas?

```
<div style="width: 260px;" class="dd-container" id="iconSelector">
<div style="width: 260px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="dd-select">
<input value="thumbs-up-1.png" class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden"><a class="dd-selected"><img class="dd-selected-image" src="/images/rewards/positive/thumbs-up-1.png"><label style="line-height: 60px;" class="dd-selected-text">Thumbs Up 1</label></a><span class="dd-pointer dd-pointer-down"></span></div><ul style="width: 260px;" class="dd-options dd-click-off-close"><li><a class="dd-option dd-option-selected">
<input class="dd-option-value" value="thumbs-up-1.png" type="hidden"> <img class="dd-option-image" src="/images/rewards/positive/thumbs-up-1.png"> <label class="dd-option-text">Thumbs Up 1</label></a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply position property value of absolute with a higher z-index, then adjust the position with left, right, bottom, and top.

```
    .menu-class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* adjust as needed */
    bottom: 0;/* adjust as needed */
    left: 0; /* adjust as needed */
    right: 0; /* adjust as needed */
    z-index: 999;
 }
```